# Align elements in the same line

Tags: html

Is there a way to align these elements in the same line. Right now it is one below the other

```
<h5>Title</h5><a id="downloadData" class="shiny-download-link" href="" target="_blank" download><h5>Download</h5></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with float property

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp

```
<div>
    <h5 style="float: left;">Title</h5>
    <a style="float: left;" id="downloadData" class="shiny-download-link" href="" target="_blank" download><h5>Download</h5></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Only use floats if your site is stuck in the year 2000, nowadays you use flexbox for that:

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">

  <h5>Title</h5>
  <a id="downloadData" class="shiny-download-link" href="" target="_blank" download>
    <h5>Download</h5>
  </a>

</div>
```